# ¿Cómo puedo comparar una variable tipo char?

Tags: c++

```
   #include<iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    using namespace std;

double operacion(int x, int y, char op);

int main (){
    
    int n1, n2;
    char o;
    int num;
    cout<<"Ingresa dos numeros: "<<endl;
    cin>>n1;
    cin>>n2;
    
    cout<<"Ingresa la operacion deseada: "<<endl;
    cin>>o;
    
    num= operacion(n1, n2, o);
    
    cout<<"El resultado de la operacion es: "<<num<<endl;
    
    
    return 0;   
}

double operacion(int x, int y, char op){
    
    int operacion;

    if(op=='+'){
    
        operacion= x+y; 
    
    }

    
}
```

Estoy tratando de crear una función que que haga la operación tecleada por el usuario

Al comparar la variable "op" no hace la operación, sino que me retorna un cero, ya probé con la función strcmp pero me da error de sintaxis.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El único problema es que no estás regresando nada en la función `operacion`, así agrega un `return` y funcionará:

```
double operacion(int x, int y, char op) {
    
    int operacion = 0;

    if(op=='+'){
    
        operacion= x+y; 
    
    }
    
    return operacion;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, tenias razón